# List of resources not used on Slurm?

Tags: memory, cpu, slurm

Is it possible to show the list of nodes that are not used by any jobs as well as the resources availaible (number of CPUs, momory) ?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible with the `sinfo` command.

What I like to use is for example:

```sh
$ sinfo -O cpusstate
CPUS(A/I/O/T)       
0/4/0/4
```

It prints the amount of total CPUs and shows which are currently allocated, idle or in *other* state.

You have also options for memory (e.g. `sinfo -O freemem`) and other metrics, visit the [official documentation about sinfo](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sinfo.html) for a full list.